# Does closing an instance of Selenium's webdriver clear all cookies?

Tags: selenium

When calling the webdriver's `close` method, if I open another webdriver, does it share the same cookies?

Comment: Why not just try it out?

Comment: Quite possibly the most unhelpful comment on SO ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/15595) and plenty of others on the web, the cookies are not shared between sessions for security reasons.

Comment: Greatly appreciated. Very interesting, unexpected, and good to know.